# No text at all in the game?

Tags: civilization-5

I just bought the game Civilization V on the AppStore (Apple) : The game seems to work but there is no text on any button, title, text field, etc. Is there a way to fix this ?

Tech info :

- MacBookPro Intel Core Duo 2,33Ghz / 4Go
- Snow Leopard
- Radeon X1600

[image]

**EDIT** :
I managed to start a game trying to figure out where was the correct buttons to click on, and actually the game runs, but there are huge display problems... I think that the Radeon X1600 is not supported...

**EDIT 2** :
I've added this in-game screenshot to explain the fact that this doesn't seems to be only a font problem :

[image]

As your see, the background is still the one of the intro (the current landscape is not drawn). The moving icons are buggy, etc.

Comment: Have you tried updating it?  Looks like a language translation problem.  You trying to play in a different language than english?

Comment: In fact, the settings of the game are in french. I know it because the intro trailer with the old man is in french. So everything is perfect for me. Except that the texts are not displayed.

Comment: This is a font issue, 100%. Sometimes Mac's built-in fonts are not compatible with "standard" fonts. That being said, I have no idea how to fix it. Do you have the French language font packs installed?

Comment: @Satanic Puppy : I've added a screenshot to show you the extend of this problem...

Comment: Have you tried different video drivers?

Comment: @Matthew : It's on a Mac. This can not be the problem...

Comment: @Pierre Ah, I see. Too bad they can't be updated independently of the OS.  Presumably Lion has newer drivers, though maybe not since it's an older card.  The minimum video card is the Radeon HD 2600 so officially you're unsupported :(

Comment: Do you think that updating the OS will fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In windows this game had its own font but sadly named same as a standard font, so text would be wrong size and hard to read. Solution to that was to find the font and download it to overwrite the standard font. Maybe it is similar thing for Mac?